# How to loop this code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have trying to loop this but fail everytime.
It´s the def create_widgets I try to loop. So I got a GUI that show a red button/box as soon something goes offline.

This is the code I tried to use.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
""" GUI """

def __init__(self, master):
    """ Initialize the Frame"""
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    """Create button. """
    import os
    #Router
    self.button1 = Button(self)
    self.button1["text"] = "Router"
    self.button1["fg"] = "white"
    self.button1.grid(padx=0,pady=5)
    #Ping
    hostname = "10.18.18.1"
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
    #response
    if response == 0:
        self.button1["bg"] = "green"
    else:
        self.button1["bg"] = "red"

root = Tk()
root.title("monitor")
root.geometry("500x500")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you want the whole function to loop on first execution?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you generally don't want to be importing modules anywhere but the start of the program.

Comment: Does my answer help? If not, please tell me so I can edit it.

Comment: How does it fail? What does it do, and how s that different than you expect?

Comment: @BryanOakley You're a little late, Bryan.

Comment: @XamuelSchulman: late for what?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach it onto `Tk`'s event loop using `Tk`'s `after` method.

```
def if_offline(self):
    #Ping
    hostname = "10.18.18.1"
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
    #response
    if response == 0:
        self.button1["bg"] = "green"
    else:
        self.button1["bg"] = "red"
```

Then, this line goes anywhere between `app = Application(root)` and `root.mainloop()`:

```
root.after(0, app.if_offline)
```

`after` attaches a process onto the `Tk` event loop. The first argument is how often the process should be repeated in milliseconds, and the second is the function object to be executed. Since the time we have specified is 0, it will constantly check and constantly update the button's background color. If that churns your CPU, or you don't want to be pinging that much, you can change the repeat time to something larger.

The function object passed in should be just that: a function object. It has the same rules as the command argument in a `Button` constructor.
If you need to pass in arguments to the function, use a lambda like so:

```
root.after(0, lambda: function(argument))
```

This works because the lambda function returns a function object, which when executed will run `function(argument)`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Comment: Hi
I´m new to programing so I don´t really understand why I get error when I write this.
NameError: name 'root' is not defined 

root.after(0, if_offline)
root.mainloop()

Comment: Try adding one indent to everything within the class.

Comment: My mistake. It needs to be `app.if_offline` not `if_offline`. I edited the answer to include that.

Comment: I get no errors now, but it still doest loop.
'def if_offline(self):'
    import os
    #Router Ping
    hostname = "182.83.0.1"
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + hostname)
    #response
    if response == 0:
        self.button1["bg"] = "green"
    else:
        self.button1["bg"] = "red"

    root = Tk()
    root.title("monitor")
    root.geometry("500x500")

app = Application(root)

root.after(0,if_offline)
root.mainloop()

Comment: @user6335058 I'm not sure about your specific example. There may be other problems with it unrelated to the looping, but those are yours to find. All I can tell you is that using `after` will attach a certain function to the `Tk` event loop and it will repeat over and over, depending on the first argument you give to `after`.

Comment: @user6335058 In the meantime if my answer helped, please accept and upvote it  :3