# Python 3 Tkinter multiple functions running at once

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a chat window for the client portion of a chat application that uses Tkinter for the GUI:

```
import socket
import select
import time
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
from tkinter import *

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 5678

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.settimeout(2)

try:
    client_socket.connect((HOST, PORT))
except:
    print("Connection failed.")
    sys.exit()
print("Connected to [" + str(HOST) + "," + str(PORT) + "] successfully")


class ChatWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        form = Tk()
        form.minsize(200, 200)
        form.resizable(0, 0)
        form.title("Chat")

        box = Entry(form)

        form.bind("<Return>", lambda x: self.sendmessage(self.textbox.get()))

        area = Text(form, width=20, height=10)

        area.config(state=DISABLED)

        area.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
        box.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

        self.textbox = box
        self.textarea = area

        p1 = Process(target=updating)
        p1.start()
        p2 = Process(target=tryrecvmessage)
        p2.start()

    def addchat(self, msg, clear=False):
        self.textarea.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.textarea.insert(END, msg + "\n")
        if clear:
            # Option to clear text in box on adding
            self.textbox.delete(0, END)
        self.textarea.see(END)
        self.textarea.config(state=DISABLED)

    def sendmessage(self, msg):
        data = str.encode(msg)
        client_socket.send(data)
        self.addchat("<You> " + msg, True)

    def updating(self):
        while True:
            form.update()
            form.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.01)

    def tryrecvmessage(self):
        while True:
            read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select([client_socket], [], [])
            for sock in read_sockets:
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    self.addchat(data)
                else:
                    self.addchat("Disconnected...")
                    sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = ChatWindow()
```

I want the `updating()` function and the `tryrecvmessage()` function to run simultaneously, so that the GUI continues to update while the client still receives messages from the server. I've tried using the `threading` module as well, but I need to have the threads created below where the other functions are defined, but the other functions need to be defined below `__init__()`. What do I do?

Comment: What is happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the functions to the `Tk` event loop using the after method, as I explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230443/how-to-loop-this-code/37230643#37230643). Essentially the syntax for `after` goes like this:

```
after(ms, command = [function object])
```

What it does is attach the function object passed in as the `command` argument to the `Tk` event loop, repeating it each time `ms` milliseconds has passed.

One caveat here: you would want to remove the `while True` from the functions as `after` would be constantly repeating them anyway.

Comment: He can't do that on `tryrecvmessage` , because receiving data from a socket server could take much time which will stop his main window from running.

Comment: That's what I figured. What do you recommend?